# ActionBarSherlock with options menu bug

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

It's a known bug in ActionBarSherlock when you use ActionBar with tabs + FragmentPagerAdapter and each fragment has its own options menu. After the configuration change the whole ActionBar becomes unresponsive. I use ABS 4.0.2 and Android 2.3.3. The bug is still present. Anybody knows how to bypass it?

Comment: when you say "configuration change", do you mean that you have a manifest setting to handle orientation changes IN THE ACTIVITY, rather than the default means, where the system recreates the activity in the new orientation?

Comment: No, I do not have such a setting in a manifest. My activities are recreated each time when device orientation is changed, and the bug is still here.

Answer (score -1):

Android's default ActionBar works the best.

You can have tabs + different fragments for tabs + different options menu for each tab with simple modification of

```
onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
```

and use of

```
invalidateOptionsMenu()
```

However to compensate for Orientation change you need to save and load the state of tabs. For that you will need to modify

```
onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

You can control Fragments behavior through

```
onResume()
```